# Existe alguma forma de criar diferentes tabelas em SQLITE3 através da mesma função python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Estou criando um bot em python através da biblioteca python-telegram-bot, e ele funciona através de comandos.
Eu sei que através do 'cursor.execute()' eu consigo criar uma tabela via python, mas a verdadeira pergunta é: existe uma forma de criar tabelas diferentes toda vez que eu chamar uma função?

```
def criarnovarodada():   
     cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE rodada1 (id, rodada, texto, autor);
""")
```

pronto, criei o cursor.execute, agora eu gostaria de criar uma table chamada "rodada2", mas utilizando a mesma função "criarnovarodada". Como proceder?

Answer (score 0):

Basta voltar ao básico da programação e utilizar parâmetros da função:

```
def criar_nova_rodada(numero):
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE rodada{} (id, rodada, texto, autor);".format(numero))
```

Assim:

```
criar_nova_rodada(1)  # Cria rodada1
criar_nova_rodada(2)  # Cria rodada2
```

Mas provavelmente você não precisa fazer isso. Dificilmente uma aplicação necessita essa criação dinâmica de tabelas. Recomendo que revise a estrutura do seu banco, pois é quase certo que não está fazendo a melhor solução.